# What is the difference between print('') and print(' ') in python?

Tags: python-3.x, space

What is the difference between print('') and print(' ') in python?

I'm very new to learning python and in order to get the correct amount of white space in my output I had to use print(' ') and print ('') on their own line. Not sure why that was needed.

```
needed_service = input('Select first service:')
print(' ')
additional_services = input('\nSelect second service:')
print(' ')
print('')
print('\nDavy\'s auto shop invoice\n')
if needed_service in services:
    print('Service 1:', ' ', needed_service, ',',' ','$', services.get(needed_service), sep= '')
else:
    print('Service 1: No service')
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. `print(' ')` will print a space character **and** a newline; while `print('')` (or `print()`) will only print the newline. It doesn't _take away_ anything.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understand why the output looked the way that it did.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print an empty line after each string, you can add `\n` to the end of it before the closing '.

```
needed_service = input('Select first service:\n')
```

This will take user input on the next line instead of directly after the colon. Using a space between quotes will show up in a printed string, but you won't see a difference between ' ' and '' if you use it in a print statement alone; using ' ' will add a space but it will still look like a normal, empty line. (You can also just use `print` by itself to print a newline if you prefer not to add onto your strings)